# Using the Dictionary method in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I am currently using the Dictionary method in C# to index a text file successfully, although in this case I would like to index more than one keyword (#HostName). I have tried adding an additional IF statement to the method although it doesn't appear to work - by that I mean it seems to break the whole method.

```
 var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 var lines = File.ReadLines("probe_settings.ini");
 var ee = lines.GetEnumerator();
 while (ee.MoveNext())
 {
     if (ee.Current.StartsWith("#PortNo"))
     {
         string test = ee.Current;
         if (ee.MoveNext())
         {
             dictionary.Add(test, ee.Current);
         }
         else
         {
             throw new Exception("File not in expected format.");
         }
     }
 }
```

Is it possible to index another term in this method? How could it be done?

Below is the file it is reading:

```
#CheckName1
HTTP Check

#PortNo1
80

#CheckName2
HTTPS Check

#PortNo2
443
```

Comment: Is the file format such that the keyword is on one line, and the value of that keyword on the next?

Comment: And when you say "it seems to break the whole method", what *exactly* do you mean by that?

Comment: As as side note you should dispose your enumerator, the best way is to put it in a `using` block.

Comment: You'll have to post a sample of your data file.

Comment: -1: There is not enough information to answer the question. "Breaks the whole method" is not sufficient for communicating the problem you are trying to solve, and your comment on `BrokenGlass`'s answer indicates you may be wanting multiple values per key. As you don't specify what you expect from a successful answer, we can't reasonably provide one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 while (ee.MoveNext())
 {
     if (ee.Current.StartsWith("#MatchOne") || ee.Current.StartsWith("#MatchTwo"))
     {
         string test = ee.Current;
         if (ee.MoveNext() && !dictionary.ContainsKey(test))
         {
             dictionary.Add(test, ee.Current);
         }
         else
         {
             throw new Exception("File not in expected format.");
         }
     }
 }
```

or use for loop

```
for( int i =0 ; i < lines.length -1 ;i++)
{
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lines[i]) && lines[i].StartsWith("#MatchOne") || lines[i].StartsWith("#MatchTwo"))
         {
             string test = lines[i];
             if ( !dictionary.ContainsKey(test))
             {
                 dictionary.Add(test, lines[i+1]);
             }
             else
             {
                 throw new Exception("File not in expected format.");
             }
         }
}
```

Comment: For some reason doing this causes the same problem, it's almost like the method halts, even the message boxes I asked to come up didnt appear, no exceptions were thrown..

Comment: @BenThorsby have you try my second method?

Comment: Hi, yes, but I get: "Error 2 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'
"

Comment: use `File.ReadAllLines` instead of `File.ReadLines`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean another test using `else if` besides `if (ee.Current.StartsWith("#PortNo"))`? I don't see why not. Post (some more) code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq and its `ToDictionary()` method instead - this would create a dictionary using any line that start with `#` as key, and the next line as value:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("probe_settings.ini");
var dictionary = lines.Zip(lines.Skip(1), (a, b) => new { Key = a, Value = b })
                      .Where(l => l.Key.StartsWith("#"))
                      .ToDictionary(l => l.Key, l => l.Value);
```

There's some overhead involved since this will iterate over the file twice (because is using `Zip()`) but that shouldn't matter for a rather small configuration file.

You can use the dictionary then like this:

```
string someValue = dictionary["#CheckName2"]; //returns "HTTPS Check"
```

Comment: And how exactly would you call something from the dictionary?

Comment: @BenThorsby: Just as you would normally - updated answer

Comment: Hmm, how strange, it returns: "An item with the same key has already been added."

Comment: @BenThorsby: Are you trying to add multiple values for the same key? If so you would need a lookup instead. I tested on your file and it works fine for me.

Comment: Hi, no I am not, I am puzzled :(